# Return all of the data in JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

this is i want to do, i want to return all the data that will come from 3 tables where `resort_id` is the `foreign key`, "all" means all the data from 3 tables that is equals to `resort_id`. I tried to use `left join` for this but didnt work the result is it returns many rows but i only have one row. Can somene help me about this?

```
"
select * 
  from resorts r
  left 
  join resort_activities ra 
    ON r.resort_id = ra.resort_id 
  left 
  join resort_gallery rg
    ON r.resort_id = rg.resort_id 
 where r.resort_id = $id
";
```

**Resort table**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      resort_id      |    resort_name   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         as       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

**Activity Table**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      activity_id    |    resort_id     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

**Gallery Table**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      gallery_id     |    resort_id     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: And what is your problem with your current SQL ?

Comment: @Ravi i only have one data but it returns many rows.

Comment: I just want to return all the data in those 3 tables in one query.

Comment: Are you sure you have only one row in activity and gallery table for the given id? Because your query is correct.

Comment: Can you add the result the query returns?

Comment: What would the desired result look like?